# SendGrid - Event Responses with Custom parameters

Tags: sendgrid

We are implementing email system for mass mailing.

As per our requirements we are going to use send grid as a third party email service providers.
The individual email activity track using post event responses from send grid to figure out percentage of spam, clicks, double clicks and bounces.

But while receiving event responses from send grid, we cannot differentiate multiple responses on same email address.

Shall it be possible that we will send some unique id with each email header sent through send grid and receive that unique email id in event responses?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do what you suggest with unique ids. Just pass your identifier as a category. Categories are POSTed back with event responses for your use.

```
X-SMTPAPI: {"category" : "some_unique_id"}
```

There is currently no limit to the number of categories you can use on SendGrid so this solution should work.

edit: The way to do this now is with [Unique Args](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/unique_arguments.html)

Comment: Yes, I already try out its also working for me. But we are sending millions of email per month. I discussed this issue with send grid support, as per their discussion they don't have any policy for limitation but in future they can have policy with category limitation.

Comment: @Brand the Unique Args link seems to be broken. Do you know which one is the new proper one?

Answer (score 1):

Now it seem possibile to send some custom parameters

http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/api/event-api/

Read the section "Custom Parameters and Categories"